# How to execute N1QL queries in couchbase 4.1 using script?

Tags: couchbase

I want to schedule daily cleanup job using scripting on Couchbase by using this N1Ql query:

```
DELETE FROM tutorial t WHERE t.title = “Mrs”
```

How can I do that in Couchbase 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cbq tool provided with the couchbase server along with other tools.
This link will help you out: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/n1ql-query.html

Comment: You can also use curl or any HTTP tool.